# Select items with no reverse relationships in Django

Tags: django

With these models:

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    recording = models.ForeignKey(Recording)

    start_sample = models.IntegerField()
    end_sample = models.IntegerField()

class Detection_method(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Event_type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Event_classification(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    method = models.ForeignKey(Detection_method)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(Event_type)
```

Events can be classified as multiple types using different detection methods.

How do I select events with no Event_classifications?

**Edit:** And related, selecting events with one or more specific classifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always an implicit reverse relation and even an `event_classification_set` manager on `Event` objects.

This will select the `Event` objects without `Event_classifications`:

```
Event.objects.filter(event_classification__isnull=True)
```

It will perform this query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM "event"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "event_classification"
  ON ("event"."id" = "event_classification"."event_id")
WHERE "event_classification"."id" IS NULL
```

Note that if you try to do the opposite

```
Event.objects.filter(event_classification__isnull=False)
```

you can get duplicate Events, one for each classification. You can eliminate them with

```
Event.objects.filter(event_classification__isnull=False).distinct()
```